# Monitor system resources in QT

Tags: qt, network-programming

Is there anyway to monitor system resources, namely network statistics (ping, download, upload) in Windows? I've looked at a couple of similar threads and one mentions using WinPcap is the only way to do this, just wanted to get any recent answers if there are any?

I've done a ping tool utilizing Window's ping.exe which works great but struggling to get ideas for other data.

Cheers!